# Xamarin, UIButton sender doesn't respond

Tags: c#, xamarin, viewcontroller

I followed the instructions from Xamarin University (unfortunately they've disabled comments so I can't discuss it with anyone)

the first viewcontroller has a storyboard id of "viewController" and the second one I'm trying to switch to has a storyboard id of "AndraViewController".

```
partial void Knapp1_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    UIStoryboard storyboard = this.Storyboard;
    AndraViewController viewController = (AndraViewController)
    storyboard.InstantiateViewController("AndraViewController");

    this.PresentViewController(viewController, true, null);

}
```

When I press the button nothing happens, I don't receive an error message or anything.

Comment: It seems ok, double check if the storyboard ID "AndraViewController" is really set in your Storyboard. Also, what happens if you try:
    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController, true);

Comment: I added the line of code you suggested, no errors, but still doesn't work. I'm guessing it has something to do with my Visual Studio then; some setting?

Comment: Have you checked if the Storyboard ID is really set on your Storyboard?

Comment: Here are screenshots of my view controllers id's.
I've tried checking and unchecking the "Use Storyboard ID" box but to no help
https://imgur.com/a/cTa4ddL
https://imgur.com/a/FXeI

Comment: Right! Is your other view controller Storyboard ID assigned with AndraViewController?

Comment: It solved itself. I tried to launch the project with the IOS Simulator instead of the Xamarin Live Player - and it worked. However, thanks for your help!